# "Invalid currency: sgd" error when running stripe-samples / grabpay-payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I am getting http response code 400 with error message `Invalid currency: sgd` when running this particular Stripe sample on GitHub - `grabpay-payment`. Log shows payment intent is created but throw the error above when try to update the payment intent with its Id.

I am guessing it's because GrabPay is currently only available in Singapore and I am using a Malaysia account. Can you help to verify ?

Comment: You'll want to reach out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) as they can both confirm the issue and advise if there's a workaround.

Comment: yups i have tagged stripe-payments as suggested by Stripe Support themselves in Github